# emails received on the server but available through POP3 or IMAP

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I set up my server to receive emails and I want to be able to read the emails through POP3.
When checking logs, /var/log/mail.log, I can see the email arriving.
If I su as the user on the server, I can see the email by typing

```
bob@september:~$ mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/bob": 2 messages 2 unread
>U  1 joe@gmail.com    Sun Feb  9 16:29  107/5813  test
 U  2 joe@gmail.com    Sun Feb  9 16:40  107/5812  test
&
```

And I do see the emails.

When I try retrieving the emails using Outlook configured to hit the server in POP3, nothing comes. Same if I use POP3 protocol.

```
{20-02-10 18:37}september:~ dude% telnet localhost 110
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot (Debian) ready.
USER bob
+OK
PASS bobspassword
+OK Logged in.
LIST
+OK 0 messages:
.
QUIT
+OK Logging out.
```

The MTA is postfix
The MDA is dovecot

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The location of mailboxes is not universal. Check the `mail_location` directive, probably in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`.

Comment: same location in dovecot configuration and postfix configuration  mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

Comment: **bsd-mailx** is looking in `/var/mail/bob`, which is probably a stale mailbox (in `mbox` format) that was created before you configured **postfix** to use Maildir.